# Give custom name to parameters of composed functions

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

So I am creating some composed functions & export them to be used in the rest of my codebase. For that I want their input parameters to have meaningful names.

Sample code:

```
const multiplyBy10 = (num: number) => num * 10;
const divideBy5 = (num: number) => num / 5;

const multiplyBy2 = pipe(multiplyBy10, divideBy5);
```

Now the newly created multiplyBy2 function takes one parameter & it is named as 'x0' due to it being composed by pipe function. Is there a way to rename 'x0' to something like 'num'?

One way I can think of is doing something like this:-

`const multiplyBy2 : (num: number) => number = pipe(multiplyBy10, divideBy5);`

As you can see, this looks quite ugly, and I am looking for a better way of doing this.

Comment: Ramda certainly doesn't offer this, and is not likely to ever do so, as it's concerned with the JS positional arguments, but not with names.  There might be some trick you could do with the `Function` constructor, but I don't know exactly how that would work.  If you're writing in Typescript and the sort of solution above works for you, that's probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

The `x0` you mention is coming from the type definitions

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2490b045819e5e3ed1f930f97006bc9d2a54a336/types/ramda/index.d.ts#L1422

It's not something you can edit on a case-by-case basis.

If you could alias `pipe`'s type to have the arguments be named `num` instead of `x0`, that *could* work

```js
declare function pipe<V0, V1, T1>(fn0: (x0: V0, x1: V1) => T1): (x0: V0, x1: V1) => T1;

interface NumPipe {
  <V0, V1, T1>(fn0: (num: V0, x1: V1) => T1): (num: V0, x1: V1) => T1
}

const numPipe: NumPipe = pipe;
```

Although, the "ugly" way you mention of manually spelling the type signature next to the definition is the most straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, "There might be some trick you could do with the `Function` constructor...".  I was curious to see how it might work, and here's one version which works.  Of course it's uglier than your original ugly version.  I would never recommend it.  But it does seem to work:

```js
const pipe = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.slice(1) .reduce((r, fn) => fn(r), fns[0](...args))

const nameParams = (names, fn) => 
  new Function(
    '$__fn__', 
    `return (${names .join (',')}) => $__fn__(${names .join (',')})`
  ) (fn)

const multiplyBy10 = (num) => num * 10;
const divideBy5 = (num) => num / 5;

const multiplyBy2 = nameParams (['numberToDouble'],  pipe (multiplyBy10, divideBy5))

console .log (multiplyBy2)
console .log (multiplyBy2 (10))
```